# SQL Server 2008 Is there a more efficient way to do this update loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First posted question, I apologize in advance for any blunders.
The table contains records that are assigned to a team, the initial assignments are done with another process. Frequently, we have to reassign an agent's records and spread them out equally to the rest of the team. We have been doing this by hand, one by one, which was cumbersome. So I came up with this solution:

```
    DECLARE @UpdtAgt TABLE (ID INT, Name varchar(25))
    INSERT INTO @UpdtAgt
    VALUES (1, 'Gandalf')
          ,(2,'Hank')
          ,(3,'Icarus')


   CREATE TABLE #UpdtQry (TblID varchar(25))
   INSERT INTO #UpdtQry
   SELECT ShtID
   FROM TestUpdate

   DECLARE @RowID INT
   DECLARE @AgtID INT
   DECLARE @Agt varchar(25)
   DECLARE @MaxID INT
   SET @MaxID = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @UpdtAgt)
   SET @AgtID = 1

   --WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #UpdtQry) > 0)
   WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TblID FROM #UpdtQry)

   BEGIN
    SET @RowID = (SELECT TOP 1 TblID FROM #UpdtQry)
    SET @Agt = (SELECT Name FROM @UpdtAgt WHERE ID = @AgtID)

    UPDATE TestUpdate
    SET Assignment = @Agt
    WHERE ShtID = @RowID

    DELETE #UpdtQry WHERE TblID = @RowID

    IF @AgtID < @MaxID
        SET @AgtID = @AgtID + 1
    ELSE 
        SET @AgtID = 1


   END

   DROP TABLE #UpdtQry
```

This is really my first attempt at doing something this in-depth. An update of 100 rows takes about 30 seconds to do. The UPDATE table, TestUpdate, has only the CLUSTERED index. How can I make this more efficient?

EDIT: I didn't define the @UpdtAgt and #UpdtQry tables very well in my explanation. @UpdtAgt will hold the agents that are being reassigned the records, and will likely change each time this is used. #UpdtQry will have a WHERE clause to define which agents records will be getting reassigned, again, this will change with each use. I hope that makes this a little more clear. Again, apologies for not getting it right the first time.

EDIT 2: I commented out the old WHILE clause and inserted the one that HABO suggested. Thank you again HABO.

Comment: Where is `TestUpdate` table structure? Seems like a `CTE` can do the job

Comment: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero. As a rule, using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is frowned upon.

Comment: HOLY CRAP! That did it! Using EXISTS in the WHILE, instead of SELECT COUNT(*), took it from 30 secs to under 1 sec. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @UpdtAgt TABLE 
(
  ID INT, 
  Name VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT @UpdtAgt
VALUES (1, 'Gandalf')
      ,(2, 'Hank')
      ,(3, 'Icarus')

UPDATE t
SET t.Assignment = a.Name
FROM TestUpdate AS t
INNER JOIN @UpdtAgt AS a
    ON t.ShtID = a.ID
```

That should do all 4 rows at once.

P.S...

If you do create tables like in your original post in future, please try and keep the naming of your columns and variables consistent with their purpose!

In your example you used `ID`, `AgtID`, and `ShtID` and (most confusingly) `TblID` (and I think they're all the same thing? [please correct me if I'm wrong!]). If you called it `AgtID` everywhere (and `@AgtID` for the variable [There's no real need for `@RowID`]) then it would be much easier to see at a glance what'd going on! The same thing goes with `Assignment` and `Name`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and suggestions on naming! I'm not sure this would work, TestUpdate in production is a decent sized table, over 100k, and I would only be looking to update a small portion of it. Which is what the #UpdtQry table would bring in, the portion that needs updating. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post. In production there would be a WHERE clause in the #UpdtQry temp table creation.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is your first attempt at something like this, I want to congratulate you on something that works. While it is not ideal (and what is?) it meets the main goal: it works. There is a better way to do this using something known as a cursor. I remind myself of the proper syntax using the following page from Microsoft: [Click here for full instruction on cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql)

Having said that, the code at the end of this post shows my quick solution to your situation. Notice the following:

1. The `@TestUpdate` table is defined so that the query will run in MSSQL without using permanent tables.
2. Only the `@UpdtAgt` table needs to be setup as a temp table. However, if this is used regularly, it would be best to make it a permanent table.
3. The `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` statements at the end are **IMPORTANT** - forgetting these will have rather unpleasant consequences.

> ```
> DECLARE @TestUpdate TABLE (ShtID int, Assignment varchar(25))
>
> INSERT INTO @TestUpdate
>    VALUES (1,'Fred')
>   ,(2,'Barney')
>   ,(3,'Fred')
>   ,(4,'Wilma')
>   ,(5,'Betty'),(6,'Leopold'),(7,'Frank'),(8,'Fred')
>
> DECLARE @UpdtAgt TABLE (ID INT, Name varchar(25))
>
> INSERT INTO @UpdtAgt
> VALUES (1, 'Gandalf')
>       ,(2,'Hank')
>       ,(3,'Icarus')
>
> DECLARE @recid int
> DECLARE @AgtID int SET @AgtID=0
> DECLARE @MaxID int SET @MaxID = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @UpdtAgt)
>
> DECLARE assignment_cursor CURSOR
> FOR SELECT ShtID FROM @TestUpdate
>
> OPEN assignment_cursor
> FETCH NEXT FROM assignment_cursor
> INTO @recid
>
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
> BEGIN
>   SET @AgtID = @AgtID + 1
>   IF @AgtID > @MaxID SET @AgtID = 1
>
>   UPDATE @TestUpdate
>   SET Assignment = (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM @UpdtAgt WHERE ID=@AgtID)
>   FROM @TestUpdate TU   
>   WHERE ShtID=@recid
>
>   FETCH NEXT FROM assignment_cursor INTO @recid
> END
>
> CLOSE assignment_cursor
> DEALLOCATE assignment_cursor
>
> SELECT * FROM @TestUpdate
> ```

Comment: A lot of the stuff I've read discourages the use of cursors, but I have minimal experience with them. Did I misunderstand about cursors?

Comment: Cursors can be bad if you overuse them, need multiple people to run the same cursor at the same time, or you are running them continually. In your case, the cursor should have a better performance than your current solution.